# react-native ios app opens and closes immediately in testflight

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight

I don't understand what the problem is.

Everything was fine when I created the app, but when I uploaded it to the app store for testing in testflight, the app starts to open and immediately closes without opening.

No errors, the application just tries to open, but fades and we get to the desktop iPhone

Comment: On Xcode run application in release mode, check app closes issue. Check app certificates, provisioning profiles and APNS certificates(if you integrate push notification) are correctly added.

Comment: everythings is okay, but app not open in release mode

Comment: check your JScodelocation on Appdelegate.m file in Xcode as `#ifdef DEBUG
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif`

Comment: i have this line: `jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];`

Comment: Don't you have else block code, which points to jsbundle in release mode. Kindly check your test flight crashes log on Xcode. window->organizer->crashes